# Error after changing web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and I am trying out ASP.net.

After I try to make any changes to the `web.config` file and try to run the application, I get "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: please post web.config file

Comment: Just checking...did you hit F5 when you were still on the web.config tab?  Visual Studio seems to attempt to browse to that location in your project.  With directory browsing turned off...403 forbidden is what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly this would be caused by not having the correct "default" document.  For example the IIS server may be looking for **default.aspx** and you have created **index.html**.

This explains in more detail:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1207657.aspx?How+to+Fix+HTTP+Error+403+14+Forbidden+The+Web+server+is+configured+to+not+list+the+contents+of+this+directory+

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help.

It was a clumsy mistake from my side.

I was hitting the Debug button in VS when the config tab/file was open.

When I hit the run Debug button from the webform it is working fine.

Thanks all.